# import _geo into Meilisearch from Laravel Model

Tags: laravel, laravel-scout, meilisearch

ok so lets start off with code

```php
return [
            'name' => $this->name,
            'user_display_name' => $this->user_display_name,
            'user_city' => $this->user_city,
            'user_region' => $this->user_region,
            'user_country' => $this->user_country,
            'profile_photo_path' => $this->profile_photo_path,
            '_geo' => [
                'lat' => $this->user_latitude,
                'lon' => $this->user_longitude,
            ],
        ];
```

So, the issue is, when I do `php artisan scout:import "App\Models\User"` it gets all the data except inside the `_geo` array. I have looked at the formatting 100 times but it looks right based on all the docs and everything. Does anyone have any idea what I am not seeing?

Answer (score 1):

There was a typo 'lon' should be 'lng'

```
'_geo' => [
            'lat' => $this->user_latitude,
            'lng' => $this->user_longitude,
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question
However, based on the documentation, I found that a latitude and longitude of 0 can be successfully imported

https://docs.meilisearch.com/learn/advanced/geosearch.html#preparing-documents-for-location-based-search

```php
            '_geo'            => [
                'lat' => $this->user_latitude ?? 0,
                'lng' => $this->user_longitude ?? 0,
            ],
```